# Invoking .Net Web Service with Php

Tags: c#, .net, php, web-services

I have a C#.Net Web Service and php client to invoke the web service.

Web Service Methods takes C# objects as parameters and returns C# objects as follows

```
Site getSite(siteID){ return Site.load(siteID) }
```

or

```
void newSite(Site site){ site.save(); }
```

I know that WSDL tool generates c# classes and java has code generator for web services.

- How can I invoke this services with Php?
- Is there any utilities, libraries, such as Pear, or any framework, like Zend, generates code for Php ?
- If I make the Objects in Php, and initialize them, then can i pass them to service calls and would that work?
- Should they be serialized ?

Comment: I dont know, that s why i asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a previous question on SO: [How to easily consume a web service from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430/how-to-easily-consume-a-web-service-from-php)

You can get to the wsdl of the .NET webservice by going to a url formed like the following:

```
http://url/service.asmx?wsdl

http://url/service.svc?wsdl
```

Comment: Thanks. Didnt see the previous questions

Answer (score 1):

Please see: [Consuming Web services in PHP](http://www.builderau.com.au/architect/webservices/soa/Consuming-Web-services-in-PHP/0,339024590,320283202,00.htm)