# Consume a .Net web service using PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client, nusoap

This is my first time with web services/SOAP...i have been trying to consume .Net web services using PHP but to no avail. I have searched and read all pages that google throws up for anything related to this but i am still lost.

The thing is the SOAP service i am trying to call has an authorization header and i can't figure out a way to authenticate my request.

I have tried the php-soapclient and NuSoap both but there is no sample code available that would help. So any help would be great.

The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response.

```
POST /OxiWalletService/Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.160.0.49
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/WS_GetData"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
  <AuthHeader xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <UserName>string</UserName>
    <Password>string</Password>
  </AuthHeader>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
  <WS_GetData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <xmlString>string</xmlString>
  </WS_GetData>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
  <WS_GetDataResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <WS_GetDataResult>string</WS_GetDataResult>
  </WS_GetDataResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can anybody please gimme a sample code on how to consume such a service.

Many thanks in advance!

This is the code that i have used to call the web service

```
<?php 

$soap_client = new SoapClient("http://172.160.0.49/OxiWalletService/Service.asmx?WSDL");

$Uid='oxigen';
$Pwd='oxigen';
$ns = "http://tempuri.org/";

//Body of the Soap Header.
$headerbody = array('UserName' => $Uid,
                    'Password' => $Pwd
                   );
//Create Soap Header.       
$header = new SOAPHeader($ns, 'AuthHeader', $headerbody);       

//set the Headers of Soap Client.
$soap_client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
$par="<Wallet><SPName>AuthenticateMerchantWebVending</SPName><Parameters>&lt;Parameter&gt;&lt;Name&gt;@Account&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;Size&gt;50&lt;/Size&gt;&lt;Value&gt;1135600016&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;Type&gt;varchar&lt;/Type&gt;&lt;/Parameter&gt;&lt;Parameter&gt;&lt;Name&gt;@Password&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;Size&gt;20&lt;/Size&gt;&lt;Value&gt;0OgknrdonyM=&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;Type&gt;varchar&lt;/Type&gt;&lt;/Parameter&gt;</Parameters><ParameterCount>2</ParameterCount><DataBase>1</DataBase></Wallet>";
$param=array('xmlString'=>$par);

$result=$soap_client->__SoapCall('WS_GetData',$param);

print_r ($result);

?>
```

and i am getting the following as output:

stdClass Object ( [WS_GetDataResult] => 2Unknown Error )

Ideas??

So it turns out you've to pass the second argument with parameters as the key of the array

meaning this

```
$result=$soap_client->__SoapCall('WS_GetData',$param);
```

should be

```
$result=$soap_client->__SoapCall('WS_GetData',array('parameters'=>$param));
```

This works now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581169/invoking-net-web-service-with-php

Comment: also check http://www.scottnichol.com/nusoapprogwsdl.htm for a tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:
    [www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php)

```
$ns = "http://tempuri.org/"

//Body of the Soap Header.
$headerbody = array('UserName' => $yourUsername,
                    'Password' => $yourPassword,
              );

//Create Soap Header.       
$header = new SOAPHeader($ns, 'AuthHeader', $headerbody);       

//set the Headers of Soap Client.
$soap_client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

Comment: Ok so this is a first. even though i have the SOAPClient enabled i am getting this error  

Undefined variable: soap_client in C:\wamp\www\soap1.php on line 14

and

Fatal error: Call to a member function __setSoapHeaders() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\soap1.php on line 14

Comment: well, you actually need to have the soap client instance, my code is partial. Post your code without the real data and we'll try to see what you are doign wrong.

Comment: for me the WSDL does not even load from the url.

Comment: Thank you so much for ure help. i figured it out and posted the solution above. THANK YOU!

Comment: You sir just saved my weekend. Wish I could buy you a beer.