# PHP web application calling a Java application

Tags: java, php, servlets

I need to develop a web application using PHP and the Apache web server. The application should call an external Java-based application which is stored in the host computer and pass the user's input value to this application which will analyse it and do something. 
I have been reading articles about PHP/Java and it seems that the best solution is to integrate a PHP into a Java servlet environment such as PHP/JavaBridge. As I am not an expert on web development and pretty ignorant on PHP, can someone tell me if this is the best solution and if not, what other possible approaches should I use it? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of application are you trying to call? Is it a command line application written in Java, a web-based Java application, an applet? These types of applications require different methods to call them.

Comment: It's a standard stand-alone application, not web-based...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The application should call an external Java-based application which is stored in the host computer and pass the user's input value to this application which will analyse it and do something.

***WebServices*** are perfectly suited here.

**Also See**

- [how-to-easily-consume-a-web-service-from-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430/how-to-easily-consume-a-web-service-from-php)
- [Java WebServices](http://java.sun.com/webservices/reference/apis-docs/index.jsp)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$parameter1='your';
$parameter2='parameters';

$output = shell_exec("java whatever.jar $parameter1 $parameter2");

echo $output;
```

*** Update ***

I do agree with Jigar Joshi, though. I think a web service would be the best option here.

Comment: This is actually the answer to the question (thus the +1 vote). As starting the java runtime is quite expensive (for a web request) and results in a high latency, I do agree with the *Update* that Web services are a better answer to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may explose your already existing java application api as web-services (jax-ws or jax-rs) and then use any application to call that. So you can write an web-wrapper around your java-webapp and then call it. First approach it better approach.