# call external web service from my controller

Tags: php, web-services

I have this Web Service:
http://www.hotelbeasain.com/webservice/wshotelbeasain.asmx

I am trying to call it from jQuery but it is not possible due to Same Origin Policy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Is there any way to call it and use the data from my controller?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It not really about Symfony but the PHP language. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24490/795876) is an answer to your question for consuming WebServices in PHP.