# Posting to an Application from a PHP script on another server

Tags: php, rest, post

Whats the best method for posting some data from a server side script, to a PHP web app on another server?

I have control over both ends, but I need to keep it as clean as possible.

I'm hoping people don't mistake this as a request for code, I'm not after anything like that, just a suitable method, even the name of a technology is good enough for me. (FYI the recipient web app will be built in Yii which supports REST if that matters).

Comment: cURL is probably the easiest.

Comment: http://at2.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the answers here mention cURL, which is fine for smaller use-cases. However if you have more complex and/or growing needs, or plan to open up access to other servers in the future, you might want to consider creating and consuming a web service.

This article makes a somewhat compelling argument [for RESTful web services over SOAP-based](http://www.infoworld.com/d/application-development/web-services-are-dead-long-live-rest-211395?page=0,1), but depending on who will be consuming the service, a SOAP-based web service  can be both simple to consume ([How to easily consume a web service from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430/how-to-easily-consume-a-web-service-from-php)) and set up ([php web service example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242355/php-web-service-example)).  Consuming a RESTful web service is easily done via cURL ([Call a REST API in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802788/call-a-rest-api-in-php)).

The choice really comes down to scope and your consuming audience.

Answer (score 2):

Use cURL: http://curl.haxx.se

If you're calling from a PHP script, you can use PHP:cURL https://php.net/curl

Probably best to do it over SSL, if you want to keep the info safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can access your REST API with [PHPs cURL Extension](https://php.net/curl).

You will find examples [here](https://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you use a framework, some have alternatives to cURL, which are easier to handle (like Zend http client).

Or for very simple purposes (and if php-settings allow this), you could use file_get_contents().