# Call Webservice from Website

Tags: html, web-services, wsdl, soapui

I have been doing some webservices testing using a tool called SOAPUI.

I have a WSDL file that I import into the soapUI tool.
I will then have to fill some parameters in that file.
I will have an "endpoint URL" to which I will have to point it.
I then run it.

I get the response (Success ) on the other side of the tool.

Now, I am planning to do all these from a Webform (Web site ) using HTML / VBScript / Javascript or whatever .. I have no ideas how whatsoever.. Can the enlightened ones enlighten me please ??

I'm pretty sue I wouldn't have given all the required inputs. Please feel free to ask.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at either of the following

1. A web service access from Javascript/HTML [refer here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14610/Calling-Web-Services-from-HTML-Pages-using-JavaScr)
2. If you have a server backend like Java something like [axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/quickstartguide.html) or [jax-ws](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-ws-tutorials/)
3. If you use PHP more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430/how-to-easily-consume-a-web-service-from-php)

Basically you are looking at a web service implementation/toolkit in any language. First decide on the language and the google for how to access web service using that language. The above links should help you for some common scenarios.